# The OAuth2 authentication request process of Office 365 forwards the link to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, office365

Currently, I am developing my web app to use Rest API of Office365. In order to do that, for the OAuth2 authentication and authorization, I follow the step in this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-office-365-exchange-online/

However, I am stuck on the second step, which the first sign in attempt on windows page. Here is the full link that I use for the OAuth2 process:

```
"https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[ClientId]&redirect_uri=http://localhost/MicrosoftAuthDemo/MicrosoftCallBack.ashx&response_type=code&resource=https://outlook.office365.com/&state=c9833f87-892a-4f94-9234-2de9832d1f49"
```

After I have done the login, instead of showing the consent page and redirecting the URL back to my web: `http://localhost/MicrosoftAuthDemo/MicrosoftCallBack.ashx`, it forwards the URL to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`, which I have no idea what it is.
That `login.srf` link shows this page:

[image]

Out of the blue, it asks for login again. However, when I try to login again, it  forwards me to the same link again: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`.

Does anyone know what's the source of the problem?

In case anyone wants to know my app registration setting in Azure portal:

1. Register settings

[image]

2. Properties

[image]

3. Secret key

[image]

4. Replay URLs

[image]

Comment: One thing you can try is to use `https://login.microsoftonline.com` instead of `https://login.windows.net`.

Comment: Also don't forget to URL-encode the parameters like `redirect_uri`. You do not need to specify `resource`. You will get back an authorization code which you will exchange for an access token, there you need to specify the resource.

Comment: Yes, it seems the article I followed doesn't work anymore. I instead followed this one https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the article where I followed is already old (posted in 2014) and doesn't work anymore.

Finally, I have fixed the problem by following the steps in this article: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

Here I would explain briefly what I have changed:

**First**, for registering the app, instead of using https://portal.azure.com, I registered my app via https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/. Somehow, they are different.

**Second**, I change the full link that I use for the OAuth2 process into:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=[Client ID]
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=[your web app link after finishing login]
&response_mode=query
&scope=[scope of your app]
```

Parameters explanation:
[image]

Comment: If you can, try to detail some things which you changed here so future visitors can try to fix their problem using your solution.

Comment: Okay I will add some detail later

Answer (score 3):

To do authorization of O365 and use REST API, here is a solution for your reference:

**First: get security Token**

Access [https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf] via Http Post method. The content of the http request is as follows.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"  
  xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"  
  xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">  
<s:Header>  
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/RST/Issue</a:Action>  
<a:ReplyTo>  
  <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>  
</a:ReplyTo>  
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</a:To>  
<o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"  
   xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">  
  <o:UsernameToken>  
    <o:Username>[username]</o:Username>  
    <o:Password>[password]</o:Password>  
  </o:UsernameToken>  
</o:Security>  
</s:Header>  
<s:Body>  
<t:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:t="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust">  
  <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">  
    <a:EndpointReference>  
      <a:Address>[endpoint]</a:Address>  
    </a:EndpointReference>  
  </wsp:AppliesTo>  
  <t:KeyType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/NoProofKey</t:KeyType>  
  <t:RequestType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Issue</t:RequestType>  
  <t:TokenType>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion</t:TokenType>  
</t:RequestSecurityToken>  
</s:Body>  
</s:Envelope>
```

The demonstration screenshot in Postman:
[image]

And the response content will include a security token as below, we can use this security token and related REST API to get Access Token of your O365 application, like SharePoint, Outlook, etc.

[image]

**Second: get Access Token**

Here i show you how to get access token of SharePoint online using the security token and SharePoint Rest API.

As long as you use the corresponding REST API, it is also used in other O365 applications.

Access [https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0] via http Post method. The content of the request is the security token that we have got above as below.

[image]

And the response as below:

[image]

We can see that there are two cookie, rtFa and FedAuth in response header, and these two cookie need to be added to the request in subsequent request.

**Third: get Request Digest**

Access [https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/_api/contextinfo] via http Post method with that two cookies which we have got above.

[image]

And the response as below:

[image]

This is the final Token we want!

Then we can use REST API of SharePoint, we only need to add this token and the previous two cookie, as shown in the following figure.

[image]